# Treat images in webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm using Google translator, sorry for the typos. 
My scenario is as follows. I have a WebService Restfull and an Android client using Jersey and JSON in Java. Can receive data and send them, my doubts are:

How receive JSON strings of images and saves it to a directory on WebService? 
I need examples of methods that perform this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the image from json using `AsyncTask` to get the image from the server and convert it into the bitmap and set it in your views.

Below are some of the examples which shows how to load image from JSON response:

[JSON parsing and Image Loading](http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/)

[Android JSON parsing to load image](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/)

Hope this will guide you.